# Unable to create the WAR of my web application on Jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am trying to deploy my web application with Jboss AS 6.x.

The problem I am facing is when I try to export the WAR file by right clicking on the project from left menu and export, there is no such option as to export the project as WAR.

I have installed JBoss Application Tools successfully. Integrated JBoss server successfully.

Where am I missing? Am I missing some necessary tools?

Comment: you tagged `maven`, check [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) out

Comment: If such option is not available from the menu, it may indicate that your project is not Dynamic Web Project. In order to make it such, go to project properties (right click) and then to project facets. And then select Dynamic Web Module and Java.

Comment: @AlexP. you are right, Now it is working perfectly fine.
saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

This option is available only if your project is Dynamic Web Project. The Java project, which is decorated with `J` letter on folder icon doesn't have the capability to export as WAR archive. But to deploy a web project you might try the approach `"Run as..."`. And choose the server configured before to run a web project.

You can't convert a Java project to a Dynamic Web Project automatically with JBoss Application Tools. But if you have MyEclipse IDE then it's easy done just by adding a web capabilities. So, choose "New..." project wizard and "Dynamic Web Project" then follow the wizard pages.

Comment: yeah actually it was a dynamic web project(when developed) but i imported it from somewhere and it didn't automatically show up as dynamic project on importing and i had to convert it into dynamic web project. Thanks anyway!